# How to read json out in php as a string?

Tags: php, json

Respected All,

I have a string which I got from an api. Now I want to extract useful data from this string. This output is a result of Json query. 
the string is

> {"PR":{"Url":"http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/custom-form/","Domain":"http://www.ididthisfilm.com","Title":"Lexicon Of Sustainability – Custom Form","Description":"Welcome to THE LIST EDIT FORM","Pictures":[{"Url":"http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Lexicon_logo_new_BETA.png","Alt":"Lexicon Of Sustainability","Title":"","SourceType":1,"Width":0,"Height":0,"ParsedAspectRatio":0}],"Videos":[],"AuthorName":null,"ExtraInfo":null},"EM":null}`

How can I get title and description and url in different variables so that I can use them in php.

Comment: Your question needs more effort. Parsing JSON in PHP has been done before. Find some code and try it. Then, when the code fails come back here. Tell us the actual result, the expected result, and the error. Show the code in the question too.

Answer (score 1):

use built-in function `json_decode` and you will get the JSON object.

```
$str=<<<CODE
{"PR":{"Url":"http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/custom-form/","Domain":"http://www.ididthisfilm.com","Title":"Lexicon Of Sustainability - Custom Form","Description":"Welcome to THE LIST EDIT FORM","Pictures":[{"Url":"http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Lexicon_logo_new_BETA.png","Alt":"Lexicon Of Sustainability","Title":"","SourceType":1,"Width":0,"Height":0,"ParsedAspectRatio":0}],"Videos":[],"AuthorName":null,"ExtraInfo":null},"EM":null}  
CODE;

print_r( json_decode($str) );
```

which outputs

```
stdClass Object
(
    [PR] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Url] => http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/custom-form/
            [Domain] => http://www.ididthisfilm.com
            [Title] => Lexicon Of Sustainability – Custom Form
            [Description] => Welcome to THE LIST EDIT FORM
            [Pictures] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Url] => http://www.ididthisfilm.com/lex_tmp2/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Lexicon_logo_new_BETA.png
                            [Alt] => Lexicon Of Sustainability
                            [Title] => 
                            [SourceType] => 1
                            [Width] => 0
                            [Height] => 0
                            [ParsedAspectRatio] => 0
                        )

                )

            [Videos] => Array
                (
                )

            [AuthorName] => 
            [ExtraInfo] => 
        )

    [EM] => 
)
```

if any error occurs, try this: [json_last_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: How you did it? I am using this `var_dump(json_decode($json_data));
var_dump(json_decode($json_data, true));`  resulting null null values.

Comment: thankyou finally Now I can go home with relax mood.